# Animation with matplotlib where points are dynamically added to a graph

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I've written a simple code which generates random points `(x0, y0)` between certain values using a while loop. After the coordinates of each point are set, that point is drawn in an empty graph which is showed at the end of the while loop.

However, I would like to set up an animation with matplotlib which would allow me to see the initial graph and the points progressively added to it as the code is calculating them. I've looked for some examples but the ones I found are mainly concerned with waves and so on and I guess I need a slightly different approach.

This is the basic code:

```
from numpy import *
from pylab import *
import random

figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=150)
x = np.linspace(-1, 4.5, 250)

h=5
a=0.5
b=4

ylim(-0.5,5.5)
xlim(-1,5.0)

i= 0

while i< 500:
    R1 = random.random()
    R2 = random.random()
    x0 = (b - a)*R1 + a
    y0 = h*R2
    scatter(x0, y0, 10, color="red")
    i = i + 1

show()
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: ANIMATION CODE

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=150)
x = np.linspace(-2, 4.5, 250)


h=4
a=1
b=3

hlines(y=h, xmin=1, xmax=3, linewidth=1.5)
vlines(x=a, ymin=0, ymax=4, linewidth=1.5)
vlines(x=b, ymin=0, ymax=4, linewidth=1.5)

ylim(-2.5,10.5)
xlim(-2.5,4.5)
grid()

def data_gen():
    i = 0
    while i< 1:
        R1 = random.random()
        R2 = random.random()
        x0 = (b - a)*R1 + a
        y0 = h*R2
        i = i + 1
        yield x0, y0


line, = plot([], [], linestyle='none', marker='o', color='r')

ax = gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

xdata, ydata = [], []

def run(data):
    x0,y0 = data
    xdata.append(x0)
    ydata.append(y0)
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, blit=True, interval=0.5,
    repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code works for me. What problem do you observe?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/animate_decay.html  This does exactly what you want.  Use `line, = ax.plot([], [], linestyle='none', marker='o', color='r')`

Comment: @tcaswell Thanks for the suggestion: I've set up a code which should center the purpose (I'll post it above). However, there's something a bit strange happening: for example, if I tell the program to draw 5 points by setting `i=5`it actually returns me 7 points instead of 5. Even if I set `i=1` there are still two more points on the graph. Why is it happening? I can't see any reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is exactly what you are looking for; in any case, you can generate random points inside the `run` function and there plot them. You do not need neither `blit = True` nor clear the axis from one frame to another.
Here is my code:

```
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6), dpi=150)
x = np.linspace(-2, 4.5, 250)

h=4
a=1
b=3

hlines(y=h, xmin=a, xmax=b, linewidth=1.5)
vlines(x=a, ymin=0, ymax=h, linewidth=1.5)
vlines(x=b, ymin=0, ymax=h, linewidth=1.5)

ylim(-2.5,10.5)
xlim(-2.5,4.5)
grid()

ax = gca()
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data',0))

def run(i):
        R1 = random.random()
        R2 = random.random()
        x0 = (b - a)*R1 + a
        y0 = h*R2
        ax.scatter(x0, y0, 10, color='red')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = run, frames = 500, interval = 10, repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

which produces this animation:

[image]

(I cut this animation to 100 points in order to get a lighter file, less than 2 MB; the code above produces an animation wiht 500 points)

Comment: Do you also know how to remove points?