# Matplotlib.animation: display points after plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was reading Jake Vanderplas's excellent piece of code for plotting a point which moves along a sine curve:

```
"""
This short code snippet utilizes the new animation package in
matplotlib 1.1.0; it's the shortest snippet that I know of that can
produce an animated plot in python. I'm still hoping that the
animate package's syntax can be simplified further. 
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def simData():
# this function is called as the argument for
# the simPoints function. This function contains
# (or defines) and iterator---a device that computes
# a value, passes it back to the main program, and then
# returns to exactly where it left off in the function upon the
# next call. I believe that one has to use this method to animate
# a function using the matplotlib animation package.
#
    t_max = 10.0
    dt = 0.05
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0
    while t < t_max:
        x = np.sin(np.pi*t)
        t = t + dt
        yield x, t

def simPoints(simData):
    x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(t, x)
    return line, time_text

##
##   set up figure for plotting:
##
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
# I'm still unfamiliar with the following line of code:
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
##
time_template = 'Time = %.1f s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
## Now call the animation package: (simData is the user function
## serving as the argument for simPoints):
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False,\
     interval=10, repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

How would you modify this code so that each point (i.e. calculated value of x, y) would remain on the figure after being plotted? Thus, toward the end of the animation, you would see all the previous dots forming the sine curve.

Comment: Actually, I got it! What I was modify the part in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842770/animation-with-matplotlib-where-points-are-dynamically-added-to-a-graph?rq=1 where xdata, ydata were defined outside of the function (as [], []) and the function to plot them just appended the new data to xdata, ydata .

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for explanation of:

```
# I'm still unfamiliar with the following line of code:
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)
```

[Python code. Is it comma operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037494/python-code-is-it-comma-operator)

---

Also, this might not help with your graphing problem, but it appears that you are definiting time_template but then not using that definition, unless it is being called globally after that point in your script.